# How to get XML or Ruby lines of code in an iOS project repo through the git command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, grep

I can easily find Swift and Obj+C lines of code from a Git Repo using

`git ls-files | grep -E  "\.swift$|\.h$|\.m$|\.json$" | xargs wc -l | grep total$`

But if I want to include all the XML and Ruby code files in the calculation, how can I achieve it? They don't have a proper file extension for the Xcode project on these files.